# How to create an "event" system for recieving packets

Tags: c++, networking, winsock, winsock2

So I've been working on some different networking programs in c++ and I've come across a problem. I use Winsock (version 2) for this, no idea if this is the best thing to use but whatever. So in winsock there is a function to receive a packet (actually 2 functions) and what it does is it waits until it gets a packet and then keeps going, freezing the program while waiting for the packet. What I think I need is some kind of "event" system where there is a function that gets called every time a packet comes in, and the program keeps running while waiting for a packet.

So basically right now if I just want to print the (tcp) packets I'm receiving I have this (first some startup code and creating the sockets and stuff):

```cpp
char buffer[4096];

while(true){

    ZeroMemory(buffer, 4096);

    recv(clientSocket, buffer, 4096, 0); //Program freezes until it receives something

    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;

}
```

But what if I have a window that I want to keep updating while waiting for a packet? The program is just going to freeze.

Comment: How about a separate thread that awaits packets?

Comment: You want to take a look at `select()`. This function allows you to check if one or more sockets need attention without blocking the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinSock offers several event-driven models for non-blocking socket operations:

- [`WSAAsyncSelect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsaasyncselect).  This would be the easiest way to incorporate into your existing code, since you already have a UI window.  You can register your `HWND` with the `SOCKET` and then add an additional window message handler to handle socket events being sent to the `HWND`.
- [Overlapped I/O](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/overlapped-i-o-and-event-objects-2) or [I/O Completion Ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports).  You can pass `WSAOVERLAPPED` structs or callback functions to [`WSARecv()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsarecv) and [`WSASend()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsasend), and you can poll operation statuses via [`WSAGetOverlappedResult()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsagetoverlappedresult) or [`GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-getqueuedcompletionstatus) in a timer or thread.

Comment: OP didn't specify it's on Windows, but if it is, `WSAASyncSelect()` is very handy indeed.

Comment: @Havenard the OP said "I use Winsock" - that is specific to Windows only

Comment: I use [WSAEventSelect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaeventselect) most of the time for non-blocking socket I/O. I find it especially useful because the event objects are not restricted to [WSAWaitForMultipleEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsawaitformultipleevents), but can also be used with the more general [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) function. But WSAAsyncSelect is better if you want window messages.